# CodeIgniter: GET CSS/JS 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a problem loading my js and css into my little project. It says not found. Please help me what to do. [image: It says 404(Not Found)]

This is where my footer is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>datatables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap-master/docs/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/boostrap.js"></script>
<script src= "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bootstrap-master/docs/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.validate.js')?>"></script>
```

While my htaccess file.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /DepEd

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your server running on the port 80 ?

Comment: what is your `base_url();` ?

Comment: His base URL judging from the errors is `http://localhost/DepEd/` @AadilKeshwani

Comment: I got weird apache port. it changes everytime. today, i got 54043, 5404.

Comment: I got $config['base_url'] = ' ';
I am using codeigniter

Comment: Ok and where exactly in `DepEd` your files are located ?

Comment: in my localhost. where my xampp is, (in htdocs)

Comment: actually the link specified in console.log is correct, but i don't know why i got 404. :(

Comment: Ok this is just to confirm is this your path `htdocs/DepEd/assets` ?

Comment: yes sir @AadilKeshwani where my css, images and js folders are located.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to change your .htaccess by

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
    </IfModule>
```

?

Comment: Still not working sir. I got redirected to the xampp.

Comment: I saw some question that is similar to my problem, and I also tried replacing my htaccess of what they answered, but still not working. :(

Comment: I guess setting `$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'`; in your `application/config/config.php` can help you solve this issue

Comment: Are you able to open ` http://localhost/DepEd/assets/js/boostrap.js` in your browser ? Try to locate this file through browser. If not than you might not have places your `assets` folder at `htdocs/DepEd/assets`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69618/discussion-between-aadil-keshwani-and-reid).